# Wrong result of a recursive relation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I took this code from [here](http://www.maplesoft.com/products/maple/compare/HowMapleComparestoMathematica.pdf) on page 15.

The code:

```
s[i_] := s[i] = 2*s[i - 1] - 3*(s[i - 1])^2
s[0] = SetAccuracy[3/10, 20]
Do[Print[s[i]], {i, 0, 40, 10}]
```

Output:

```
3/10
0.33333333333333
0.3333333
0.3
0.*10^62
```

The answer must converge to `1/3`.

How can I fix this?

Edit:
I corrected the code.

Comment: You are right. I changed the code a little bit but because before that I used the right code the result did not change for me.
What is the solution to the new code presented. How can I fix the error.

Comment: When I set accuracy more than 25, I get 0.3 which is close to the right answer. How can I prevent this type of problems?

Comment: be sure to `Clear[s]` each time you make a change

Comment: I'd like to point out the results shown are right from the linked Maple book.  This deserves an explanation more so than a "fix"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily fix this by surrounding the *computation* with `SetPrecision`, not the initial value:

```
ClearAll[s]
s[i_] := s[i] = SetAccuracy[2*s[i - 1] - 3*(s[i - 1])^2, 20]
s[0] = 3/10;
s[40]

(* Out[14]= 0.33333333333333333333 *)
```

Let me say something about the page you referred to. To quote the text below this example:

> There is **nothing** in the computation to warn the user 
>   that the results may not be reliable at every step. For 
>   example, there is no accumulation of round-off error, 
>   which mathematicians and engineers are used to 
>   seeing as a warning sign that they may be getting 
>   problematic results.

This is not true. Let me show a screen-shot of this very page

> [image]

As you can see, the last result is shown in red, which means something went wrong. When you hover over the result with the mouse, you get the warning *No significant digits are available to display*. This says, that errors have accumulated to a degree, where the result is unusable.

Furthermore, *Mathematica* is aware of the decrease in precision which can easily verified by using `Precision`. Let me use your initial example for that

```
ClearAll[s]
s[i_] := s[i] = 2*s[i - 1] - 3*(s[i - 1])^2
s[0] = SetPrecision[3/10, 20];

Precision /@ {s[1], s[2], s[10], s[25], s[40]}
```

and you get

> {19.4616, 18.866, 14.0496, 5.01873, 0.}

which shows, that *Mathematica* keeps track of numerical errors.

As a side note: If you are about to choose which product you use in future, I beg you not to read such material. The only purpose of it is to discredit the competitor. Unfortunately this stuff is available on [the other side](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/compare-mathematica/compare-mathematica-and-maple.html) too. If you have to choose, then choose what your friends use, because they can help you. Choose what your university uses, because then you might get it for free. Choose what you can pay for because some products are cheaper or give it for student prizes. Etc..

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I have been using Mathematica for two years. I just came across to that page.

Comment: *1 nice.  IIRC that red flagging of the error is a fairly new feature. The book may have been correct on that point depending on what version they used.

Comment: @george The image I used *is* directly from this book! So the Maple guys have seen this error too.

Comment: @yashar I just wanted to make sure that you read this material with the right attitude, which means for fun. In our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica) on mathematica.SE we have had a lot of laughts about the ongoing flame war these days. If it were not so sad, it would be laughable.

Comment: the point is its not an error.  The reason this example is a red herring is the calculation is performing a newton iteration to find the root of `(1-3x)/x ==0 `. The accuracy of Newtons method does not depend on the accuracy of the initial *guess*, but by specifying `SetAccuracy` you are asking mathematica to keep track of the accuracy of the guess through the whole calculation. It correctly reports that if you really cared about the sensitivity of the result to the initial guess 20 digits accuracy is not sufficient.